Show dates when a ticket changed to a specific status
I want to have an overview in Jira that allows me to see when (as in "at what date/time") a ticket has been changed to a specific status.
Example: Assume, my workflow is super simple and goes like this: ready -> doing -> done. For this, I'd like to get a list of all tickets with resolution = Done, and print out the date/time, when exactly each ticket was moved to the 'doing' and/or 'done' status.
So far, I've been playing around with JQL queries, but I can't find a way to fetch the dates of the status changes (and the resulting status name) via the search field reference https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver0904/advanced-searching-fields-reference-1188766214.html
Is there a simple way to do it via the web interface or will I need to go via the Jira-API to fetch those dates?
